# Stream data type implementation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, stream, algebraic-data-types, custom-data-type

I have course for Haskell programming at my university. And I must implement my own datatype "`Stream`" and its some functional:

```
data Stream a = a :> Stream a
```

I have problems to implement a function "`streamToList`":

```
streamToList :: Stream a -> [a]
```

It must take an object of "`Stream`" and return an infinite list. But I don't know how to take elements of this object. How can I take the elements of this stream?

Also, I want to ask: what is the way to initialize an object of this datatype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined your data type as

```
data Stream a = a :> Stream a
```

This serves as a pattern, a template for how it can be *used*. "Used" means, both *created* and *accessed*. In other words, *interacted* with.

Values of this type can be *accessed* with the pattern to the left of `=` in definitions,

```
foo (a :> restOfAs) = a : foo restOfAs
```

(what's the type of this function?)

Values of this type can be *created* using it as a code pattern to the right of `=` in definitions, e.g.

```
bar i = i :> bar (i+1)
```

or

```
baz [x]    = x :> baz [x]
baz (x:xs) = x :> baz xs
baz []     = error "can't be empty"
```

or

```
quux x = xs  where  
         xs = x :> xs
```

(what are the types of these functions?)

Comment: glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 3):

> It must takes an object of "Stream" and returns an infinite list. But I don't know how to take elements of this object.

With pattern matching you can "unpack" the data wrapped in the data constructor, so something like:

```
streamToList :: Stream a -> [a]
streamToList (x :> xs) = …
```

Here `x` is the first item of the stream, and `xs` is a `Stream` of items.

I leave implementing the body of the clause (the `…` part) as an exercise. You will need recursion to "walk" over the rest of the stream.